# How to send a delayed notification email for multiple list items on the email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, multiple-values, outgoing-email

How do I send an email through sharepoint which contains a list of multiple values?

Basically I want a list of only the items that are pending in the list to be displayed on the email.

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to call REST API `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list>')/items` with `$filter` to get items from the list based on conditions in the workflow. Then, loop through REST API Results suing loop and add information of items to the string. Send an email and use the string as the email body.

Refer to this blog:

[SharePoint 2013: Designer Workflow To Iterate Through REST API Results Using Loop](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013)

[Workflow look through multiple items and send one email](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/)